# How to access abstract class property inherited to internal class

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a internal  class "B" which is derived from a abstract class,example

```
abstract class A
{
    private int _abc;
    public int abc
    {
       get{return _int;}
       set{_abc=value;}
    }
}
internal class B:A
{

}
```

I need abc in different assembly,can i access it ??? please help me.

Comment: Make your class `public` or use the attribute `[InternalsVisibleTo("OtherAssemblyName")]`

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to safe it internal by the some reason, you have a few ways to access from the external code

1) You can use [InternalVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to grant access to access internals to friendly assemblies

```
[assembly:InternalVisibleTo("Test.dll")]
```

2) You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access a member of an object

```
object obj = <instance of your internal type>;
var value = obj.GetType().GetProperty("abc").GetValue(obj);
```

3) You can introduce a public interface which will provide a contract to access abc property

```
public interface IAbcAccessor
{
  int abc {get; set;}
}

internal abstract class A
  : IAbcAccessor
{
    private int _abc;
    public int abc
    {
       get{return _int;}
       set{_abc=value;}
    }

    int IAbcAccessor.abc
    {
       get{return abc;}
       set{abc = value;}
    }
}
```

External code can access property by the using Interface

```
var accessor = (IAbcAccessor)<instance of your internal type>;
var value = accessor.abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of B or declare anything to be of type B outside of the assembly that B is declared in. E.g

```
B b = whatever
```

Or

```
A b = new B()
```

Is not allowed outside of the assembly that B is declared in.

However if you have a public method

```
public class C
{
   public static A MakeAB()
   {
      return new B();
   }
}
```

in the assembly that B is declared in, then use can say

```
A a = C.MakeABe()
```

in any assembly, as the type B does not need to be known by the caller of C.MakeAB()